# Icon in Action Bar on Lollipop

Tags: android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I have tried putting `android:icon` and `android:logo` under Application and the launcher activity in the Android Manifest. I have also tried programatically setting the logo and setting the icon. And finally I have also tried including `icon="my_icon"` and `logo="my_logo"` in the AppCompat styles.xml. None of this has worked and I am still left icon less. Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried `setNavigationIcon()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Google decided to disable the action bar icon beginning in Lollipop without documentating the change.  There is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926127/home-button-in-action-bar-not-working-in-lollipop) with more information.